# how to remove xmlnode within a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, xml

At the following code i use foreach loop to check each node in nodelist and remove some of them.
after i remove one node the foreach loop throw the following error:
"The element list has changed. The enumeration operation failed to continue".
How can i avoid it?

```
public static XmlNodeList Scan(XmlNodeList nodeList)
        {
            string elementValue = null;
            foreach (XmlNode xmlElement in nodeList)
            {
                elementValue = xmlElement.InnerText;
                if (elementValue.Length >= 6 && elementValue.Substring(0, 3) == "999")
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else 
                {
                    XmlNode node = xmlElement.ParentNode;
                    node.RemoveChild(xmlElement);
                }
            }

            return nodeList;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're not simply removing items from the collection you're looping over, I'm not sure if "use a for loop" will work.

The following takes two steps:

1. Create a regular list of all the elements you want to detach from their parents.
2. Detatch those elements from their parents - by iterating over the regular list, which isn't affected by the detachings.

```
public static XmlNodeList Scan(XmlNodeList nodeList)
{
    List<XmlNode> toRemove = new List<XmlNode>();

    foreach (XmlNode xmlElement in nodeList)
    {
        string elementValue = xmlElement.InnerText;
        if (elementValue.Length < 6 || elementValue.Substring(0, 3) != "999")
        {
            toRemove.Add(xmlElement);
        }
    }

    foreach(XmlNode xmlElement in toRemove)
    {
        XmlNode node = xmlElement.ParentNode;
        node.RemoveChild(xmlElement);
    }

    return nodeList;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer, sadly, is to not use foreach, but to fallback on the very bulletproof "for()".

```
for(int i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    object myObject = collection[i];
    collection.Remove(myObject);
}
```

In this case, I loop backward in the collection, and remove one object at a time. That way, I can never have an invalid index.

Comment: Thank you for answer. this method arrises another issue, now when i removed a node it removes all it child nodes also and that can be a problem.

Comment: Of course you have to adapt it to your need and put the conditions you want in there. The example I've written was only to show how I can edit a collection within a for loop while editing it in a foreach doesn't work. If removing a node removes all it's sub-children too, then it would have done it with any solution. It depends what you want to do with the sub-children. Do you want to re-add them to the collection you were parsing, like if you were only collapsing a hiearchy?

Comment: i need to keep some of the sub childer in the same node list so later i can extract the element value and path for later use.
the reason i want to remove the other elements and not creae a new list is that in a new list i will lose the original xpath of elements.

Comment: this type of code is the very problematic. iterating and modifying a collection in place. -1

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop instead from

```
for(I=length-1;I>=0;I--)
```

For each is used for enumerating and you cannot delete while enumerating the list. Also the loop must start from the last element to avoid any shift when you delete an element.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alterative: [Convert xmlnodelist to list<>](https://forums.asp.net/t/1842614.aspx?Convert%20xmlnodelist%20to%20list%20)

`XmlNodeList` has a method `Cast` and can be used as follows:

```
var listOfNodes = new List<XmlNode>(xmlNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>());
```

Answer (score -2):

You are not allowed to change a collection used during a `foreach` iteration. You can use `For..loop` instead

```
for(int i=0; i<nodeList.Length; i++)
{
   //remove nodeList[i];
}
```